# hsqldb table is not empty after it has been cleared and then reconnected to

Tags: java, hsqldb

After inserting some data and running a few queries, i decided to delete data from table. However, when i ran both

TRUNCATE TABLE Mytable

and

DELETE FROM Mytable

,the next time i connect to the database, it is not empty, and queries return results.
It has continued even after i have deleted the folder of database.
It should be noted, that queries on the table that are run immediately after truncatre or delete return no results, as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the default behavior of the database is auto-commit off and you're operating within an implicit transaction. When you disconnect, everything you just did is not written to the DB (a `ROLLBACK` has occurred).

You need to issue `COMMIT` before closing your connection. This finalizes your changes in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Do you do explicit close() on the connection?

HSQLDB has a textual format for logging operations, and recreates database state after restart executing that file. If you do not let DB to close cleanly, trailing commands may not be written to the file and will not be executed again when you reconnect.

You can actually look into the database script file (*.script) after your have disconnected and see if your commands are recorded.

Comment: After i have done both (COMMIT and closing the conncetion), the problem finally lifted off. Thanks a lot!